# pl sql update rows with value from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In agent table I have field bossId which is an Id of other agent,
so I generated data for all other fields in agent table and now I need to set bossId for all the rows.

So each row need to select agentId for its bossId field from the same table.
there can be some agents with the same boss but agent cant be boss of himself.

this is the table I have

```
+---------+------+--------+
| agentId | name | bossId |
+---------+------+--------+
|     123 | aaa  |        |
|     124 | bbb  |        |
|     125 | ccc  |        |
|     126 | ddd  |        |
+---------+------+--------+
```

wanted resault:

```
+---------+------+--------+
| agentId | name | bossId |
+---------+------+--------+
|     123 | aaa  |    124 |
|     124 | bbb  |    123 |
|     125 | ccc  |    126 |
|     126 | ddd  |    123 |
+---------+------+--------+
```

so the empty column bossId needs to be filled with AgentId of the same table
how to do it in pl sql?

UPDATE:
tried using this code which seems to  be ok but I get errors

```
begin
  for i in 1..17 loop
    update policeman p
    set bossid = (select p2.officerid
                 from policeman p2
                 order by dbms_random.value
                 where rownum = 1)
                 where rownum =i;
    end loop;
    end ;
```

error:

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 18:
PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure for this?

Comment: So you just want to set `bossID` to some different but otherwise random `agentID`?

Comment: yes I need to set random value from agentId to bossId

Comment: @מיכאל ביתן You may want to try this `update tbl set bossId = (select DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE*max(agentId) from tbl t1, tbl t2  where t1.agentId <> t2.agnetId)`. Since I'm not sure whether this'll work (and can't try it myself), I'm posting as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
update t
    set bossid = (select max(bossid) keep (dense_rank first order by dbms_random.random)
                  from t
                 );
```

Note:  This may not be very efficient if your data is not small.

Answer (score 0):

This should work provided agentid is unique.

`update t tgt
    set bossid = (select max(agentid) 
                    from t src 
                   where tgt.agentid<>src.agentid);`